# Dimension of subspace over $\mathbb F_q$

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a finite field of $q$ elements.
Let $G$ be a group with two generators $\{a,b\}$. Let $A$ be a non-trivial one-dimensional representation of $G$ over $\Bbb F_q$.

Consider the set of maps
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
S:=\{f:G\longrightarrow A\mid f(g) - h\cdot f(g) = f(h) - g \cdot f(h),\ \ \ \forall g,h\in G \}. (\star) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here the "$\cdot$" denotes the action of $G$ on $A$.

> Claim: $\operatorname{codim}_{A^2}S = 1$.

> proof attempt: Consider the embedding
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
>   S &\hookrightarrow A^{2}\\\\
>   f &\mapsto (f(a), f(b)).
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> Intuitively, I can say that $S$ is an affine subspace of $A^2$ of codimension one over $\Bbb F_q$ because $S$ is defined by one non-trivial relation.

But it seems difficult to formally get $f(a)$ from $f(b)$ using the relation ($\star$), so I find this proof unsatisfactory. Is the claim correct? Is there a better way to prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $A$ here?

Comment: What if you replace $A$ with $A\oplus A’$?

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo, A is a non-trivial one-dimensional representation of G, I fixed it.